# $\lambda_{\min}$ is $ \frac{1}{N}\max|\sum_{j}y^TX_j|$ rather than $\max|\sum_{j}y^TX_j|$?

Tags: scikit-learn, lasso

Given the objective function
$$\text{argmin}_{c}(\Vert y - Xc \Vert_2^2 + \lambda\Vert c \Vert_1)$$

by taking the derivate 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial c}(\Vert y - Xc \Vert_2^2 + \lambda\Vert c \Vert_1)$$

it can be [proved](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/365292), $\lambda_{\min} = \max|\sum_{j}y^TX_j|$ is the smallest $\lambda$ that makes the solution to the objective a zero vector.

However, when I did it in practice, I found this $\lambda_{\min}$ is not the smallest, here is my code:

```
x_1 = np.linspace(-1, 1, 30)
x_2 = 2 * x_1 + 0.01 * np.random.rand(30)
x_3 = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 30)
y = 0.1 * x_1 + 0.5 * x_2 

l1 = abs(np.inner(x_1, y))
l2 = abs(np.inner(x_2, y)) 
l3 = abs(np.inner(x_3, y))
lambda_min = max(l1, l2, l3)

x = np.ones((30, 3))
x[:, 0], x[:, 1], x[:, 2] = x_1, x_2, x_3
lambda_n = lambda_min

while True:
    lambda_n = lambda_n * 0.95
    lasso_test = Lasso(alpha=lambda_n, fit_intercept=False)
    lasso_test.fit(x, y)
    temp = lasso_test.coef_
    if np.sum(temp) != 0:
        print('lambda_n = ', lambda_n)
        break
print('lambda_min = ', lambda_min)
```

`lambda_min` is far greater than `lambda_n` which is the smallest `lambda` that makes `lasso_test.coef_` a zero vector.

It is only when I change

```
lambda_min = max(l1, l2, l3) / 30 # number of examples
```

will `lambda_min` and  `lambda_n` be the same.

Given this, the formula for calculating $\lambda_{\min}$ should be 
$$\frac{1}{N}\max|\sum_{j}y^TX_j|$$

I believe there is nothing wrong with the theory, then what is wrong with my code?

Comment: nothing wrong with your code. the objective function sklearn-kit lasso does minimize is not $\frac{1}{2}||y-Xc||_2^2$ but $\frac{1}{2n}||y-Xc||_2^2$, hence $\lambda_{min}= \frac{1}{n} \max_j|X_j^Ty|$.

Comment: @ Thank you! I just overlooked the objective function in the documentation...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer:

There is nothing wrong with your code. The additional $\frac{1}{n}$-factor of $\lambda_{min}$, you observed in python using the sklearn Lasso function, is an immediate consequence of the objective function used in the python.

The Lasso-function from the sklearn-kit in python minimizes $$\frac{1}{2n}||y−Xc||_2^2 + \lambda||c||_1$$ instead of $$\frac{1}{2}||y−Xc||_2^2 + \lambda||c||_1.$$

As a consequence the smallest value of $\lambda$ at which the Lasso will result in all $0$-coeffcients is given by $$λ_{min}=\frac{1}{n}\max_j|X_j^Ty|.$$

(Note: Arguments leading to the value of $\lambda_{min}$ can for example be found here: [Lasso and Ridge tuning parameter scope](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210040/lasso-and-ridge-tuning-parameter-scope/283049#283049))

Comment: In many practical scenarios, this value of $\lambda$ does give you the optimal value. So, one standard practice that I have come across is the `three-sigma rule', where you compute the standard deviation of $\frac{1}{n} X^T(y - Xc)$ and set $\lambda = 3 \mathrm{std}(\frac{1}{n} X^T(y - Xc))$.

Comment: @Thank you for sharing this! I will try this in my code!